# How to optimize an image processing class

Tags: java, android, image-processing, image-optimization

I have the following class that processes a Bitmap to place a fisheye distortion on it.

I've run my app through TraceView and found that virtually all the processing time is spent looping through the bitmap.
One developer has suggested not using float as this will slow things down where graphics are concerned. Also using math.pow() and ceil() are not necessary?
At the moment to place the effect by looping through the entire bitmap takes around 42 seconds, yes seconds:)
I've tried replacing the floats with ints and that has reduced the time to 37 secs, but the effect is no longer present on the bitmap.
The arg k is originally a float and sets the level of distortion eg 0.0002F, if I pass an int the effect doesn't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to optimize this process? Once I've optimized it I'd like to look into perhaps not looping through the entire bitmap and maybe putting a bounding box around the effect or using the algorithm below that determines whether a pixel is within the circle with radius 150.

```
class Filters{
    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;
    int [] s;
    private String TAG = "Filters";
    long getRadXStart = 0;
    long getRadXEnd = 0;
    long startSample = 0;
    long endSample = 0;
    public Filters(){

        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside filter constructor");
    }

    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){
        //Log.e(TAG, "***********INSIDE BARREL METHOD ");

        float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
        float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;

        int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
        int height = input.getHeight();

        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic
       // Log.e(TAG, "***********dst bitmap created ");
          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);

          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);

          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********xscale ="+xscale);
          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********yscale ="+yscale);
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********filter.barrel() about to loop through bm");
          /*for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);

              }
            }*/

          int origPixel;
          long startLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                 origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
                 getRadXStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
                getRadXEnd= System.currentTimeMillis();

                float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);

                sampleImage(input,x,y);

                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150 ){
                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                }else{
                    dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                }
              }
            }
          long endLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long loopDuration = endLoop - startLoop;
          long radXDuration = getRadXEnd - getRadXStart;
          long sampleDur = endSample - startSample;

          Log.e(TAG, "sample method took "+sampleDur+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "getRadialX took "+radXDuration+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "loop took "+loopDuration+"ms");

        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********filter.barrel()  looped through bm about to return dst bm");
        return dst;
    }

    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {
         startSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
        s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

      int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));

      endSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){

        int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
        int [] scalar = new int[4];
        scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
        scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
        scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
        scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
        return scalar;
    }

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;

    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){

      float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }



}// end of filters class
```

**[update]**
I've created the arrays as instance variable and instantiated them in the Filter() constructor. Is this what you meant? The app was running at 84 secs(mistake), but now runs at 69 secs. there seems to be no GC logged out either.

```
class Filters{
    private float xscale;
    private float yscale;
    private float xshift;
    private float yshift;
    private int [] s;
    private int [] scalar;
    private int [] s1;
    private int [] s2;
    private int [] s3;
    private int [] s4;
    private String TAG = "Filters";
    long getRadXStart = 0;
    long getRadXEnd = 0;
    long startSample = 0;
    long endSample = 0;
    public Filters(){

        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside filter constructor");
        s = new int[4];
        scalar = new int[4];
        s1 = new int[4];
        s2 = new int[4];
        s3 = new int[4];
        s4 = new int[4];
    }

    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){
        //Log.e(TAG, "***********INSIDE BARREL METHOD ");
        Debug.startMethodTracing("barrel");

        float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
        float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;

        int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
        int height = input.getHeight();

        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic
       // Log.e(TAG, "***********dst bitmap created ");
          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);

          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);

          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********xscale ="+xscale);
          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********yscale ="+yscale);
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********filter.barrel() about to loop through bm");
          /*for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);

              }
            }*/

          int origPixel;
          long startLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                 origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
                 getRadXStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
                getRadXEnd= System.currentTimeMillis();

                float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);

                sampleImage(input,x,y);

                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150 ){
                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                }else{
                    dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                }
              }
            }
          long endLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long loopDuration = endLoop - startLoop;
          long radXDuration = getRadXEnd - getRadXStart;
          long sampleDur = endSample - startSample;

          Log.e(TAG, "sample method took "+sampleDur+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "getRadialX took "+radXDuration+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "loop took "+loopDuration+"ms");

        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********filter.barrel()  looped through bm about to return dst bm");
          Debug.stopMethodTracing();
        return dst;

    }

    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {
         startSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
       // s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

     /* int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);*/

       s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
       s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
       s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
       s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));

      endSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){

        int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
       // int [] scalar = new int[4];
        scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
        scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
        scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
        scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
        return scalar;
    }

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;

    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){

      float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }



}// end of filters class
```

Comment: you may to try posting this on the code review stack: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @joe ok thanks, i've posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, your code is doing the following:

```
for (every pixel in bitmap){
    getPixel();
    ...do something to pixel...
    setPixel();
}
```

The `getPixel()` and `setPixel()` function calls are relatively expensive. Instead of calling them over and over again in your loop, you could try to get all of the pixels into an array using [getPixels()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), and then access each pixel through the array. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715840/improving-speed-of-getpixel-and-setpixel-on-android-bitmap).

If that is still not sufficient, try coding the above in C++ through the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: @jim lim Hi, yes i coded the app last week to do this and then used the "Bitmap.createBitmap(array,x,y,config);" method. it took processing from 50 secs to 6 secs! thanks

Comment: Lim hi, i'm thinking that the ndk maybe the way to go. Do i need ms visual studio for phones to integrate c++ with android? or do i just need any c++ compiler to create the class files then call them through the ndk? thanks matt

Comment: No, you don't need any Microsoft technology to develop stuff for Android. Download the NDK and work through some of the [sample applications](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples) to see how to use it. In a nutshell, you write the C/C++ code and use the compiler provided by the NDK. I have also written about the NDK [here](http://blog.jh-lim.com/2011/07/compiling-open-source-libraries-for-android-part-2/) and [here](http://blog.jh-lim.com/2011/06/compiling-open-source-libraries-for-android-part-1/).

Comment: Having said that, be careful with NDK optimization. Please read [this](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/238-10-android-ndk-tips/).

Answer (score 2):

First off - measure some parts of your function and see where the bottlenecks are.  Don't try and optimise by guesswork.

Having said that, I'll now attempt said task :)

Doing a `sqrt()` per pixel is pretty expensive - you're comparing to a constant, so instead, square the constant and compare the squared value with that:

```
if( ( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150*150 ){
```

Also using `pow(x,2)` to square something is probably calling the library function for `pow()`, converting your `float`s to `double`s, doing a general-purpose power-raising algorithm and converting back to `float`s.  Just use `x*x` instead.

```
if(((i-centerX)*(i-centerX) + (j-centerY)*(j-centerY)) <= 150){
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is avoid creating/recreating the int arrays in 'sampleImage' and 'getARGB' by instantiating them once outside the two nested loops and passing them into those methods. This wouldn't be best practice from a code maintainability standpoint. However, it would avoid the repeated object creation, array initialization and garbage collection overhead. These tend to be much costlier than the arithmetic operations in the remainder of the code.

Comment: @btreat yep i'll try this as when i run the app there seems to be alot of GC before the image is displayed

Comment: @turtleboy - yes, this is what I was suggesting. It looks like it yielded a 15-20% improvement which is a good start. One other optimization opportunity would be to store some of the values that go into the calculation of s[0-3] at the end of sampleImage in local variables.

Comment: @turtleboy - You could also try changing the 'if (Math.sqrt(something) <= 150)' to 'if (something <= 22500)' to avoid the relatively expensive sqrt calculation.

Comment: @btreat ok thanks for that. excluding the sqrt() has shaved off a further 9 secs so it runs @ 60 secs now. I'm not sure what you mean by "store some of the values that go into the calculation of s[0-3] at the end of sampleImage in local variables".

Comment: @turtleboy - there are a number of intermediate calculations at the end of sampleImage which get recalculated with each s element calculation. (ex. '(1-x)*(1-y)'). There are some gains to be had by assigning local variables the result of these intermediate calculations and then reusing the variable values in the calculation of the s elements. There are other places where the same strategy can be applied, calc_shift (x1-cx), getRadialX (x-cx), and getRadialY (y-cy).

Comment: @btreat ok cool i'll have a look. i've put the bitmap into an array as it is processed, instead of calling dst.setPixel(). This by itself has got processing down to 14 secs! i'm now sorting a bitmap overlay which is a subset of the original so there are less pixels to loop through, the effect needs tweeking but it's running at 6 secs now:) thanks